# Calculating the sum of different unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to achieve something like in the picture attached. I could able to achieve rest but calculation of Highlighted part. Formula or VBA code is preferred. Here is the image for what I'm trying to achieve.-

[image]

Comment: The result in highlighted part, is it sum of numbers from column3 or number of appearances?

Comment: Sorry,Forgot to add that part.It is sum of numbers

Comment: Have you tried a [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) or [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) function? This doesn't appear to be too difficult it you tried something.

Comment: Have to explored doing a pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could able to solve it by sumifs method as told by Jeeped.Formula goes Like

```
   =SUMIFS(Sheet1!Column3:Column3,Sheet1!Column1:Column1,Sheet2!Column2-row1value,,Sheet1!Column2:Column2,Sheet2!Column1-row2value)
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: Check your answer as accepted so the question will be not unanswered any more.